# How can I do to display and hide a tooltip from Materializecss?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I hope you're fine. I have a question, vut first I'm gonna show a code to explain myselft better.

```js
function Tooltip () {
var values = $("#And_Or").val();

if (values == 4) {
$('body').on("mouseover",'.dropdown-content', function(){
    $("#tool-new").tooltip("hide");
});
} 
else if (values == 5) {
alert("here I have to put the code to show the tooltip again");
}
    }
    
 $('select').change (Tooltip);
 Tooltip();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready (function() {
      $('select').material_select();
    });
    $('select').material_select('destroy');
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50});
</script>

<div class="col s12 offset-s4">
    <a id="tool-new" class="tooltipped" data-tooltip="Please select more than one category" data-position="right" data-delay="120">
        <select class="and-or" id="And_Or" name="a_o[]">
            <option value="4" selected="selected">And</option>
            <option value="5">Or</option>
        </select>
    </a>
```

I just want to know: How to show and hide the tooltip if the value of the select is 4 or 5. ?? I'm using the framework Materializecss